# finding depth of node in a binary tree not BST

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a binary tree not bst  ,I need to find the depth of a node in that binary tree 
Is there any other way to achieve other than level order traversal using some dilimeter to main the count of level .

As input  I  have the root node of the tree and one of the node of the tree for which i need find the depth.

I want to have some recursive way to find this

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do a BFS you can do a DFS (and you can also do it recursively).

Comment: As your question really seems to be a homework question, I strongly suggest you to look on your favourite search engine how DFS works.

Comment: Since the tree is not a BST, the worst complexity will be O(n). Thus any kind of traversal (pre-, post-, in-) would help you where you just keep comparing the current node with the input node. All these traversals use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

pseudo-code for DFS function, the first call will be `DFS(root)`.

```
DFS(node v, integer d)
  visited[v] = true
  depth[v] = d

  for each u such that u is adjacent to v
    if visited[u] == false
      DFS(u, d+1)
```

Comment: You don't need the visited (acyclic) nor the depth variable (because you're only looking for one value, no need to go through every node).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an additional parameter in your recursive function to indicate depth.

Comment: No need for an additional parameter, you can simply use the return value of your function.